# HTML form for file upload won't return file name

Tags: php, html

I have a simple HTML file with a form to upload a file and PHP code to process the uploaded file. I've tried a bunch of `input` types and they all work except for `input type="file"`. Nothing gets displayed. The code is attached.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="test.f" id="test.f">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The processing php code is:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello world";
  echo $_FILES["test.f"];
?>
```

Comment: `test.f` isn't a good way to define those.

Comment: read the manuals http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and while you're on PHP.net => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to see what's going on/off.

Answer (score 0):

you should call the file by name if it does not work please change the file name in your form

```
name="test"

$_FILES["test"]['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmet. Changing the name from "test.f" to test and implementing your suggestion did the trick. It is working now.